# CakePHP 3 - Reusing Controller Logic

Tags: controller, cakephp-3.0, dry

I have been wondering about this before, I'll take my current application as an example.

In this application we have Users, Apps and a much of other models. All these models are modified normally, with `add`, `edit` and `delete` actions. The point is the controller logic behind this is basically identical for each model. However, the model name is of course different everywhere.

**Question: what is a proper way of reusing the standard controller actions for different models?**

I know `AppController` code is shared, so that would be a place to start. But then I can't figure out how to do the model selection properly.

An example of the core code of an `edit` page would be:

```
$entity = $model->get($id);
$model->patchEntity($entity, $this->request->getData());
if ($model->save($entity))
    //...
else
    //...

$this->set(compact('entity'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following the CakePHP's naming conventions then follow this

In your AppController:-

```
$modelName = $this->name;    //This will give you the model name
$model = $this->$modelName;  //Instance of the  model object
$model->find('all');
```

EDIT:-

> Let us consider you have two controller
>
> 1. ProductsController
>    2.CategoriesController    -->//Both extends the AppController

And your **add()** is same for both the controller,
Then in your both ProductsController and CategoriesController

```
public function add(){
  parent::add();        //this will call to the add() of AppController
}
```

Then in you AppController

```
public function add(){
   $modelName = $this->name;    //This will give you the model name
   $modelObject = $this->$modelName;
   $entity = $this->$modelObject->newEntity($this->request->data, ['validate' => false]);
   $this->$modelObject->save($entity);
}
```

Comment: That's already helpful. But that still leaves the question where the code should be placed that specific URLs can be used.

Comment: @Roberto Answer update, let me know does it make any sense or not :)